# Is '我还需要多加练习' okay as a dance video caption?

Tags: translation

I want to upload a video of me learning a dance but I make several mistakes so I want to say something like 'I need more practice' or 'more practice needed'. is  我还需要多加练习 a natural way of saying this or would I need change it?

Comment: for confirmation feed **多加** ,  **还需要**  to online dictionaries (if not already done),bkrs:多加小心,请你多加指导,请您多加指教,病人对饮食要多加检点,这个人滑得很, 要多加注意,etc.还需要:您还需要什么?它还需要再收紧些,有些事还需要商量,etc., in fact search web with 还需要多加练习 resulting in sites containing exactly this text

Comment: Are you saying that you want to practice dancing or uploading that video?

Comment: I will upload this video and then I want to say 'I need more practice' for the title/caption or as a response to the video or a text that can go along with the video if that makes sense?

Comment: It is natural and perfect. You can use it.

Answer (score 1):

我还需要多练习 (I still need to practice more) already expressed what you wanted to say, but the statement seem plain, and in a matter of fact tone.

我还需要多**加**练习 (I still need to **increase** practice **more**) .  emphasize the keenness in your intention.

'加' in '我需要多加' (+ verb without object), just like your caption, is short for '增加' (increase)

If there was an object, then '加' would be short for '施加'  or '加以' (apply to), for example,  对你的孩子**多加**管教 (**apply more** discipline to your child)

> *is 我还需要多加练习 a natural way of saying this or would I need change it?*

It is very natural, nothing wrong at all.

Comment: I would consider 多加 not as *increase* but as *apply more* here. Like *practice* in American English, 练习 can be used for both noun and verb. IMO if you say "多练习" it means increase+practice(v.) but "多加练习" means apply more+practice(n.)

Answer (score 0):

It's perfect. No more improvements are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Quite authentic! Personally I prefer 我还需要多加练习 to 我还需要多练习 because it sounds a bit more polite and formal, appropriate for the situation when saying to the public. But the latter would suits more when you say to your friend in person.